# C++ library not able to locate another library it uses

Tags: c++

I am building a C++ Console Application with custom built SDK. I have the header files and the libraries but I do not have the source code (Implementation).

In one particular case, because of being in different namespaces, a method in one class (Lets say Class A) is not able to access a Class B.

How can I fix this issue knowing that I don't have the Source code.

In the main function, I create an object reference by writing the following command:

```
Event *event=new Event();
```

On writing this statement, I get the following compiler error:

> (Event.o): In function
>   com::egi::services::mff::api::Event::setBeginTime(EGIBase::EGIXStringWrap)':
>   Event.cpp:(.text+0xacd): undefined reference to
>   EGIBase::EGIXStringWrap::getStringCopy[abi:cxx11]()'

Code is as follows:

```
#include "Event.h"
#include "EGIXStringWrap.h"
int main()
{
    Event *event=new Event(); // This is where the error crops up.`
}
```

PS: `EGIXStringWrap` and `Event` are the classes.
The setBeginTime() method of Event calls the getStringCopy() method of EGIXStringWrap

Comment: Please explain what is it that you are trying to do. Since you don't have access to Class A's private scope, how are you trying to access Class B?

Comment: This is a good example of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), you have a solution you want help with, but you don't tell us the problem you are actually trying to solve. There might be other solutions. Please try to elaborate on your problem, and also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), code says more than a thousand pictures.

Comment: In the main function, I create an object reference by writing the following command:

Event *event=new Event();

On writing this statement, I get the following compiler error:

(Event.o): In function `com::egi::services::mff::api::Event::setBeginTime(EGIBase::EGIXStringWrap)':

Event.cpp:(.text+0xacd): undefined reference to `EGIBase::EGIXStringWrap::getStringCopy[abi:cxx11]()'

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example (including the call to the compiler). It's impossible to say definitively what is wrong...

Comment: It is not a compiler error. It is a linker error.

Comment: The error message is garbled.

Comment: Was the SDK built by someone else? Are you sure it exports the symbols you're looking for? If you do an `objdump -t that_sdk.o`, do you see familiar symbol names anywhere? Have you included said *.o* file in your build command? Remember, it's not enough to just include the header file (interface), you need to link the library (implementation) too.

Comment: I have done what you asked. I also went ahead and put all the .o files inside one library and included only that library. I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case one of our other customers hits this issue, it is just a link order problem; the libraries are fine. Contact our support if you have questions- EGI.

Answer (score 1):

> (Event.o): In function
>   com::egi::services::mff::api::Event::setBeginTime(EGIBase::EGIXStringWrap)':
>   Event.cpp:(.text+0xacd): undefined reference to
>   EGIBase::EGIXStringWrap::getStringCopy[abi:cxx11] ()'

Given what you have posted, it means that the function setBeginTime() of the Event Class, in the namespace *com::egi::services::mff::api*, has an argument of type *EGIXStringWrap* that belongs to the *EGIBase* namespace.

All is well till here, since the compiler keeps resolving after that line. We can deduce that the namespace *EGIBase* is visible to the library of the class *Event*.

**Assumption:**

Then, the compiler can't find a reference to *getStringCopy*, inside the *EGIBase::EGIXStringWrap* namespace, which is in a binary form (maybe a .o) expected to be built with a C++ 11 compatible compiler.

**Given that my assumption is correct:**

First of all, it is unlikely that you can do anything, given that those libraries are given to you already compiled, better contact their provider.

Secondly, *getStringCopy* is in the same namespace, *EGIBase*, so it must be visible.

Apart from that, I find it unlikely that the produced binary library is incompatible with a library of a previous C++ version (although not impossible).

Comment: Will changing the header files contents do any good to the scenario to help my situation.

Comment: The header files, are just declarations of what you're going to use. Your problem comes from the definition (implementation) of those things. You have no access to the actual code through the .h files. So I dont think there is something that you can do (except maybe decompile the libraries etc, but that's extraordinarily difficult).